# How to merge multiple arrays or json into one in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

**Background**

It's a WordPress plugin dev issue. There is an API that returns dynamic url addresses in an array:

```
array(4) {
    [0]=>string(22) "https://t.somedomain.com"
    [1]=>string(20) "https://somedomain.com"
    [2]=>string(23) "http://192.168.2.209/km"
    [3]=>string(23) "http://somedomain2/km"
    ....
}
```

I've been able to retrieve the array above and save it into a PHP  `$urls`.

Each of one url addresses above can return a JSON response after a `GET` operation, like if I `GET` one url it will respond like below:

```
{
    "name":"HR",
    "floor":3,
    "staff": [
        { "name":"John", "info":[ "Java", "Google", "Market" ] },
        { "name":"Alex", "info":[ "PHP", "Swift", "Market" ] },
        { "name":"Duke", "info":[ "HTML", "Market" ] }
    ]
}
```

**Goal**

GET all json contents from all urls and merge into one, and decode these JSON so php can operate these data.

**Progress so far**

As now all urls are stored in variable `$urls`, I can use `foreach()` to get the JSON contents in all `$urls`.

```
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $response = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get($url));
    $obj = json_decode($response);
    // var_dump($obj);
}
```

This will return the results from all urls, but separated one by one.

Because the urls will be changed, and there might be huge numbers of urls, so it won't be wise to use:

```
array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

**The question**

Is there any possible to merge every `$response`(json) into one?

Or is there any possible to merge every decoded php objects into one?

Open to any suggestions. Thank you for your attention to this.

Comment: You should merge the decoded responses, not the JSON.

Comment: What do you want the merged result to look like? How should it handle duplicate keys among the results?

Comment: @Barmar Right! Thanks! But how?

Comment: Check [`array_merge_recursive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)

Comment: @Barmar There won’t be duplicated ones in my situation, and thank you I will dig into the link :)

Comment: So only one `name` key in all the objects?

Comment: Then just call `array_merge()` after each call.

Comment: Or put all the response in an array, and use `array_merge(...$array)`

Comment: Thank you @Barmar I finally figured it out with your help, using array_merge() haha, I've posted the code below. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Barmar, I was taking this problem too complicated, after tried and tried, I have figured out the solution to this:

```
    $merged = array(); 
//Here to declear this $merged is an array.

    foreach ( $urls as $url ){
        $response = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get( $url ) );
        $obj = json_decode( $response );
            if(is_array($obj)){  //prevent empty or error ones goes to next step
                $merged = array_merge($merged,$obj);
//Yes still have to use arrary_merge() function, add one to $merged after another 
//till the loop is end. 
//So $merged will contain all the decoded json data.

            }
    }
    $result = json_encode($merged); 

//This is an example we can now deal with $merged with php, 
//sort, insert, modify staff... 
//here I transcoded $merged to a JSON again for further output.
```

Above code is working.
Didn't quite familiar with the array_merge(), this should be simple from now on.